# How to replace p element with div and a class in bootstrap 4.5

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

For consistency, I want to use `<div class='something'>BIO</div>` instead of `<p>BIO</p>`.

In bootstrap 4.5, is there some equivalent class I can mention that gives me the same thing?

I'm not good at CSS so sorry if this is a trivial or wrong headed quesiton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Bootstrap, `p` and `div` are both block level elements -- `p` uses `margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 1rem;` from _reboot.scss. Unless its parents use classes and your `div` inherits the appearance (e.g., a parent is `<div class="container lead">`) you can simply use `<div class="mb-3">BIO</div>` and have a very similar appearance to normal `p` elements.

Outside of HTML semantics, there is nothing that prevents you from simply doing `<div class="mb-3">BIO</div>` though I would recommend `<div><p>BIO</p></div>` simply for screen readers and simplifying the appearance inheritance.

Additionally -- Bootstrap sets a lot of appearance at the body level and uses classes to adjust only the necessary styles to achieve the intended effect. The appearance of both `div` and `p` are set at the body level from _reboot.scss:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: -apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",Arial,"Noto Sans",sans-serif,"Apple Color Emoji","Segoe UI Emoji","Segoe UI Symbol","Noto Color Emoji";
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #212529;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```